# selenium - webdriver - firefox 64 bit linux

Tags: linux, firefox, selenium, webdriver

Trying to test selenium/webdriver, running ff8/fedora 13/64bit.

Trying to do a simple test of using the sendkeys function to set an input textbox.

I'm running into issues that appear to point to native events not working correctly. Tried the  selenium IRC channel with not much success.

It appears that the "x_ignore_nofocus.so" file is not implemented correctly, which apparently affects the ability to correctly handle native events.

If you've managed to get selenium/ff running on centos/rh 64 bit, to do the sendkeys function, I'd like to talk to you.

Thanks..

tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you enable native events for firefox like below?

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.setEnableNativeEvents(true);
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
```

Answer (score 4):

C#:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.EnableNativeEvents = true;
```